# Problems with partition table

Tags: data-recovery, clockworkmod-recovery, partitions

I have a Prestigio 5044 Duo (PAP5044) with MTK6589.
Basically, what I was trying to do was to resize /data partition, beacause it was only about 950Mb, by shrinking Internal SD card (/emmc) partition. For that I used Meteos MTK6589 Apllication.

After going all the steps I found out that Android OS was hanging during boot (like half-way to boot up, and it freezed with no error messages). Though, recovery (I have CWM) boots well.
After doing some research I found out, that partition table of the device was messed up after `/cache` partition. So, all system and recovery partititons are fine.

Here is fdisk output:

```
~ # fdisk -lu /dev/block/mmcblk0
Warning: ignoring extra data in partition table 5
Warning: ignoring extra data in partition table 5

Disk /dev/block/mmcblk0: 3853 MB, 3853516800 bytes
1 heads, 16 sectors/track, 470400 cylinders, total 7526400 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes

              Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks  Id System
/dev/block/mmcblk0p1            1024        1022  2147483647+  5 Extended
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary
/dev/block/mmcblk0p2           26624       47103       10240  83 Linux
Partition 2 does not end on cylinder boundary
/dev/block/mmcblk0p3           47104       67583       10240  83 Linux
Partition 3 does not end on cylinder boundary
/dev/block/mmcblk0p4           93184      105471        6144  83 Linux
Partition 4 does not end on cylinder boundary
/dev/block/mmcblk0p5          134144     1465343      665600  83 Linux
/dev/block/mmcblk0p6         7556096        1022  2143706111+ 83 Linux
```

And here are `/proc/partitions` and `fstab`:

```
~ # cat /proc/partitions 
major minor  #blocks  name

 179        0    3763200 mmcblk0
 179        1          1 mmcblk0p1
 179        2      10240 mmcblk0p2
 179        3      10240 mmcblk0p3
 179        4       6144 mmcblk0p4
 179        5     665600 mmcblk0p5
 179        6     129024 mmcblk0p6
 179        7    2901504 mmcblk0p7
 179       64       2048 mmcblk0boot1
 179       32       2048 mmcblk0boot0
 179       96   31338496 mmcblk1
 179       97   31334400 mmcblk1p1
~ # cat /etc/fstab 
/dev/block/mmcblk0p6 /cache ext4 rw
/dev/block/mmcblk0p7 /data ext4 rw
/dev/block/mmcblk0p8 /emmc vfat rw
/dev/block/mmcblk0p5 /system ext4 rw
/dev/block/mmcblk1p1 /sdcard vfat rw
/dev/block/mmcblk1p2 /sd-ext auto rw
```

So, on `mmcblk0` there must be 10 partitions, and now there are only 6, according to fdisk.

I have two ideas how it is possible to restore partitions:
1) manually with `fdisk`, though it doesn't seem like a very good idea
2) I've found some info about **scatter file** for MTK-based devices, seems like it contains all the partitioning info; I have no idea how to get and use that file, though.

What should I do to recover my device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t know the asked partition restore process, but there is a solution that works, and the phone will work again. 
You will need
1.  1.0.42 full image ROM for Flashtool 
2.  SP Flashtool
3.  EBRtweak
4.  CWM 6.0.4.4

Solution:
1.  Extract 1.0.42 ROM
2.  Copy the EBRtweak into the ROM folder, and run with the asked option (like 2,5 GB) 
3.  Delete the EBR*.bak from the ROM folder
4.  Copy the CWM 6.0.4.4 recovery.img to the ROM folder
5.  Run CheckSum_Generate.exe
6.  Flash with SP Flashtool the MT6589_Android_scatter_emmc.txt file from the 1.0.42 ROM folder. 
7.  Boot into recovery mode and go to mounts and storage: format /data, format/cache 
8.  Reboot system.

If you need any of those files, write me and I'll send it to you.

Comment: Thanks for reply. How does " 1.0.42 full image ROM for Flashtool" differ from a typical ROMs I can get form different websites, if it even differs?

Comment: It's not differs from other ROMs, it's just a special one that you can flash with Flashtool. And with Flashtool, you can re-partitionate the data. But write me an email if you need it.

Comment: Yeah, looks like this way it would be easier. Can you see my email in profile?

Comment: Sorry, I can't see it.